# django-registration simple backend setup

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm trying to add django-registration to the tutorial application in the django docs, using the [simple backend](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cde/docs/simple-backend.rst?at=default).

So far, I included the URLconf `registration.backends.simple.urls`, like so:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    url(r'^polls/',     include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/',     include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/',  include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    )
```

What do I do next?
Also, which templates are required for the simple backend, as opposed to the default backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For template, create a folder name "**registration**" in your template folder.

Then create a file for each registration action :

- `registration/registration_form.html` :  registration form
- `registration/activate.html` : activation page
- `registration/activation_complete.html` : activation complete
- `registration/registration_complete.html` : registration complete
- `registration/registration_closed.html` : disabllowed registration

For registration form page, django return form model in variable name's "**form**". You can call it in your template like this :

```
<form action="/accounts/register/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Some folks have created these templates already and are sharing them on GitHub: https://github.com/macdhuibh/django-registration-templates